# How do you find the most occurrence in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Hi guys I've found a solution but cant understand this line of code can someone explain this please?

```
frequency[commentors[v]]=(frequency[commentors[v]] || 0)+1; // increment frequency.
```

Comment: This is basically the same as `frequency[commentors[v]] += 1`. But this would give an incorrect result when the initial `0` value is not set since `undefined + 1` results in `NaN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get the existing value or `0` if it hasn't been set: `frequency[commentors[v]] || 0`
2. Add `1` to the number
3. Assign it to `frequency[commentors[v]]`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at it:

```
if (frequency[commentors[v]]) {

  // the key is already set so we can increment its value safely without producing NaN:
  frequency[commentors[v]] = frequency[commentors[v]] + 1;

} else {

  // key does not exist yet so we set its inital value to "1":
  frequency[commentors[v]] = 1;

}
```